# ES6 classes: is it possible to access the constructor of a child class from the parent?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

Using ES6 class syntax, is it possible to create a new instance of the current class from the parent? For example:

```
class Base {
    withFoo() {
        return new self({ foo: true });
    }
}

class Child extends Base {}

(new Child()).withFoo();
```

I'm looking for something similar to PHP's `new self()` syntax.

Comment: In JavaScript, the "class" *is* the constructor.

Comment: What's the reason for wanting this behavior?

Comment: @Mjh Any situation where you want the base class to contain custom constructors (e.g. factory methods). In my case, I need a method to operate on immutable objects from the base class.

Comment: Since constructor can only be one, you can't have custom constructor**s**, you can only have 1 constructor. You basically want PHP's statics that can pass different arguments to the class' constructor, thus instantiating the object with different parameters. Did I get it right or am I wrong? You have a problem that you're trying to solve, so it might be better to ask about that problem instead of perceived solution, [which is also known as XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and I think we might have an XY problem here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access the current instance's constructor via `this.constructor`.

Comment: @cainlevy: Maybe you are not calling it with `new`? `new this.constructor(foo, bar)`

Answer (score 0):

In a static methods you can use this (which then represents a class reference) to instanciate objects of child classes.

Working Typescript code:

```
class Base {
    foo: boolean
    constructor(param: {foo: boolean}) {
        this.foo = param.foo;
    }

    static withFoo() {
        return new this({foo: true}); // key line: use this instead of self in _static_ methods
    }
}

class Child extends Base { }

const child = Child.withFoo(); // will return an instance of Child with foo set to true

console.log(child); // Child {foo: true}
```