# Instantiating from this in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm not sure this is possible, but this is what I'm trying to achieve...

```
abstract class Animal<T> {
  breed(mate: Animal<T>) {
    return new [this kind of animal]()
  }
}

class Cat extends Animal<Cat>{
  
}


let cat1 = new Cat();
let cat2 = new Cat();
let kitten = cat1.breed(cat2);
```

Is this type of thing possible, or would I need to create a `breed` method for every type of animal?

In ES6 JS you could use `new this.constructor()` but in Typescript this isn't possible:

```
abstract class Animal<T> {
  breed(mate: Animal<T>) {
    return new this.constructor()
  }
}
```

will give an error:

```
this expression is not constructable.
Type 'Function' has no construct signatures.
```

Comment: Note that this isn't really a *TypeScript* question, the types are correct (although `breed` should also have a return type of `Animal<T>`); you need to know how to do this in *JavaScript*, as it's happening at runtime.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ES6 classes: is it possible to access the constructor of a child class from the parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42161828/es6-classes-is-it-possible-to-access-the-constructor-of-a-child-class-from-the)

Comment: You can do this in ES6, but I'm not having any luck in Typescript...

I get the error: "This expression is not constructable. Type 'Function' has no construct signatures."

Comment: Oh interesting. Could you give an [mre] of that, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(property) Object.constructor: Function` is **Function**, In typescript you cannot do `new` on top of it also `this.constructor` is not recognized as value of constructor type by `TypeScript`, but you can cast to `any` to get the new instance. In your case something similar to below -

```
abstract class Animal<T> {
  breed(mate: Animal<T>) {
    return new (<any>this.constructor);
  }
}
```

In JavaScript every function is considered as constructor when used with `new` hence the JavaScript code is working fine without any issues.